# Using checkboxes to select objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, html

I am making a visualforce page for my custom object Opportunity Package to add multiple to a related list all at once.

In order to accomplish this I will need to know which ones are being selected.

I'm not terribly familiar with javascript or I would find a way to do it using that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Visualforce Code:**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!packageMap}" var="oppPackage">
          <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputPanel >Select</apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="selected" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputPanel >Package</apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText >{!packageMap[oppPackage].Name}</apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputPanel >Products</apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText >{!packageMap[oppPackage].Products__c}</apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputPanel >Price per Unit Discount</apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText >{!packageMap[oppPackage].PPU_Discount__c}</apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputPanel >Exipration date</apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText >{!packageMap[oppPackage].Expiration_Date__c}</apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest way is probably to create a commandbutton (called "save" or something) at the top of the grid. This commandbutton should call a controller method that inserts the checked records.

How to tell the controller which records are to be saved? Use a wrapper class. See here to begin https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

You'll end up looping through a list of your wrapper class records and storing the checkbox in a boolean value for each wrapper class record. FYI, looping through a list is better than looping through the keys of a map and getting each value using the key. In your case above, even if you didn't need the wrapper class, it would be better to loop through a list defined in the controller as packageMap.values().

Comment: n.b -- the 'looping' occurs when building the list of sobjects to update from the list of wrapper objects whereas the wrapper object boolean property `isChecked` is updated directly on the wrapper object based on the binding from the VF row to the wrapper object via the `var=`

Comment: Literally exactly what I needed, thank you very much!